# ARRAYFORMULA with IF with AND with OR functions

Tags: array-formulas

Cannot create an arrayformula that works. The function is

```
=if(or(and(B2="ACCEPTED";C2="CONCLUDED";D2=0;E2=0);B2="CANCELLED";B2="REJECTED");"NO";"YES")
```

Cannot transform this into ARRAYFORMULA.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsOWA.png

Linl to spreadsheet : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O4fz_l41qQYc9dgk01ks6ewnY440IdQqE5kWXl1gY-8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

`OR` and `AND` does not work in `ARRAYFORMULA` in the way one might expect.

You need to use `+` instead of `OR` and `*` instead of `AND`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IFS(
    B2:B = "",,
      ((B2:B="ACCEPTED") * (C2:C="CONCLUDED") * (D2:D=0) * (E2:E=0))
    + (B2:B="CANCELLED")
    + (B2:B="REJECTED"),
      "NO",
    True,
      "YES"
  )
)
```

[image]